# all xml tags are not getting deleted at single script run in php

Tags: php, xml

i've the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<server>
  <gcm regId="APA91-yySYdx_Ydvkl2pQNB54yDpJRq4SnWvJCpsaCm6hT3LlXqP1S-3uTiXlXwylPKmrFSZbsA" email="mozi"/>
  <conversation ip="mozi1" email="mozi">
    <chat>abc</chat>
  </conversation>
  <conversation ip="mozi1" email="mozi">
    <chat>abc</chat>
  </conversation>
  <conversation ip="mozi1" email="mozi">
    <chat>abc</chat>
  </conversation>
  <conversation ip="mozi1" email="mozi">
    <chat>abc</chat>
  </conversation>
  <conversation ip="mozi1" email="mozi">
    <chat>abc</chat>
  </conversation>
</server>
```

I want to delete all the `conversation` tags where `email=mozi`.

I am doing this from the following code.

```
public function DeleteConversation()
{
    $conv=$this->xmlDom->getElementsByTagName("conversation");

    foreach ($conv as $conversation) 
    {
        if ($conversation->getAttribute('email') == $this->adminEmail) 
        {
            $this->xmlDom->documentElement->removeChild($conversation);
        }
    }
    $this->SaveChanges();
}
```

Now when I run the script and this function is called. The loop only works only 3 times.i.e it deletes only `3 records`.When I run the script next time it deletes one record and next time one record.So that's how all the five records get deleted.Why this is happening?

I want them all to delete in a single go. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is troublesome to use `foreach` combined with removing elements from a `DOMNodeList`. As the elements are removed, the list is altered in-place but `foreach` does not compensate for that.

> NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects in the DOM are live; that is, changes to the underlying document structure are reflected in all relevant NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects.
>
> – [The DOM Structure Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1590626202)

Two common approaches are:

1. **Build a collection of elements to remove, then remove them**

   ```
   foreach ($conv as $conversation) 
   {
       if ($conversation->getAttribute('email') == $this->adminEmail) 
       {
           $to_delete[] = $conversation;
       }
   }

   foreach ($to_delete as $conversation)
   {
       $conversation->parentNode->removeChild($conversation);
   }
   ```
2. **Remove the first element from the list until there are no more**

   ```
   $conv = $xpath->query('/server/conversation[@email="'.$this->adminEmail.'"]');
   while ($conv->length > 0)
   {
       $conv->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($conv->item(0));
   }
   ```

Comment: it worked thanks.I was doing the same mistake in c# today :) my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to you manipulating the set you're looping through.  Try creating a copy of the array like so:

```
public function DeleteConversation()
{
    $conv=$this->xmlDom->getElementsByTagName("conversation");
    $copy = $conv;

    foreach ($copy as $conversation) 
    {
        if ($conversation->getAttribute('email') == $this->adminEmail) 
        {
            $this->xmlDom->documentElement->removeChild($conversation);
        }
    }
    $this->SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: And can you provide the entire class perhaps and how you're instantiating it?

Comment: thnx for the help @Micah I finally got it resolved from salathe's answer.